# condicion en sql

Tags: mysql, select, condiciones

Mi problema es que tengo un campo crédito con cuatro cifras de la tabla cliente donde la primera cifra es un 0 o un 1 y quiero hacer una select con una condición de que si es un 0 el primer valor me devuélva las tres ultimas cifras pero con en negativo y si es un 1 las tres ultimas cifras en positivo. 
Es decir si tengo un 1890 que me devuelva 890 y si tengo un 0909 que me devuelva -909.

No se como habría que imponer el IF en la select para devolver la substring correcta.

Comment: Saludos y bienvenido, por favor lee [ask] edita y añade lo que llevas intentado

Answer (score 3):

Alvaro, puedes utilizar CASE realizar una condición. SUBSTRING, para extraer algunos caracteres y CONVERT para convertir los datos al formato que necesites. Te dejo un modelo de como queda la consulta.

```
SELECT
   CONCAT((CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT('0999', CHAR(4)), 1, 1) WHEN '0' THEN '-' 
ELSE '' END), SUBSTRING(CONVERT('0999', CHAR(4)), 2, 3)) AS NEGATIVO,
   CONCAT((CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT('1890', CHAR(4)), 1, 1) WHEN '0' THEN '-' 
ELSE '' END), SUBSTRING(CONVERT('1890', CHAR(4)), 2, 3)) AS POSITIVO;
```

[image: Consulta en MySQL]

Answer (score 0):

Suena a un mal diseño, deberías guardar los valores numéricos como lo que son: números.

En el -menor- peor de los casos, sería mejor guardar el signo en otra columna.

Pero si en realidad lo necesitas, la alternativa a la manipulación de la cadena puede ser algo como:

```
SELECT if( col/1000 < 1, -col, col-1000 ) x
  FROM ( SELECT '1890' col 
         UNION 
         SELECT '0909'
       ) t
```

Considerando que siempre son 4 dígitos y que los negativos comienzan con cero.